# Measuring rurality

Tags: geography

An inhabitant of Vermont boasted on his web site that that is the most rural of all the fifty states.

But Alaska, with fewer than a million people in an area bigger than France, has a far lower population density.

**If** you spread the people out uniformly over the land, they're farther apart in Alaska than in Vermont.

**But** they're not spread out uniformly.  If distances between neighbors is averaged over people rather than over land, the average Alaskan might be much closer to his neighbors than the average Vermonter.

So how should one measure rurality?

Comment: You can get the urban/rural ratio from Census. Does it not satisfy your requirement?

Comment: That doesn't explain what the Census Bureau did. Classifying every inhabitant's place of residence as urban or rural involves drawing some sharp boundaries between urban and rural, and there may be some arbitrariness in that, and at any rate the question remains: how did they decide?

Comment: [This](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/urban-rural.html) is how Census does it. You're trying to make your own definition, which would require the location of each person. It's impossible.

Comment: The Census Bureau does know the location of each person, and even without that, one has considerably more information just from populations of census tracts than one would get from any method that draws sharp lines between urban and rural and goes on from there.

Comment: No, census does not know the location of every person. You may get population statistics from Census on some level of geo granularity, maybe CBSA or ZIP, but then your argument about arbitrariness of these divisions will kick in.

Comment: @Aksakal The Census nevertheless has made such high-resolution data freely available that people *can* hope to formulate, test, and successfully use their own definitions of rurality, even though there will be some error as you suggest.  Unlike ZIP-level data (which are not really even geographically well defined and average 7500 people each), the average number of people summarized in a Census Block is only 35.

Comment: @whuber, I didn't know that. I bet whatever you do with it will end up with the same answer as simple Rural/Urban ratio for the OP's question

Comment: @Aksakal You might be right, but I cannot say because I don't know what the OP really means by "rural." That's not a question we can answer on this site--and I doubt it's a question anyone could objectively answer. Are we to understand "rural" in terms of how people make their living? Degree of self-reliance? Aspects of culture? Distances between dwellings? Proximity to urban areas? Psychology of the inhabitants? Speed of access to various technologies such as healthcare and broadband communications? The possibilities are endless and I doubt they all lead to the same measure of "rurality."

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me to not be a methodological question but a conceptual or theoretical one. Definitions of rural, like any socially constructed definition (and this is clearly one, since apart from population density, how do you define it?) need to be based on your purpose.

I work for a federal grantmaking agency. We need to define rural for policy and political-related purposes. We have federal regulations that tell us we need to use Rural Urban Continuum Codes (RUCC, also called Beale codes), produced by the USDA's Economic Research Service (see [here](http://www.ers.usda.gov/topics/rural-economy-population/rural-classifications.aspx)). But where is the cutoff point? There are also the Rural Urban Commuting Area (RUCA) codes, which are down to the Census tract and consider proximity to urban centers as well as population. But again, where is the cut point? We met with the ERS folks and other researchers and no one would stake a claim to say "This is how you should do it" - everyone threw it back at us, and said we needed to base it on our own conditions and purposes. That is good, logical advice I would give any researcher who needs to define rural. Think about what is your objective in defining rural - what needs to be different enough about what you are looking at for it to be considered a separate category? It is not necessarily even an ordinal distinction, e.g. Large Urban, Small Urban, Suburban, Rural, Remote Rural, because the differences you may be looking for may be substantial, nonlinear, and non-monotonic.

If this is a question just out of curiosity, then do whatever the heck you want, of course.

Comment: +1 This wonderfully thoughtful response has turned what initially appeared to be an unanswerably vague question into an informative and interesting thread.

Comment: Google knows exactly where all their Andorid users are at any given time, they can identify concentrations of people at any location. In fact, that's how they compute traffic conditions in their Navigation app, imho